# convert joda-time seconds to formatted time string

Tags: java, jodatime

say I have 110 seconds that I want to convert to `01:50` or `00:01:50` or such. How do I do that in joda-time? I load the number into Seconds but then toString is not doing the conversion for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(0, 0); // midnight
time = time.plusSeconds(110);
String output = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss").print(time);
System.out.println(output); // 00:01:50
```

Note this answer is valid for amounts of seconds less than one full day (86400). If you have bigger numbers then better use a formatter for durations (in Joda-Time called `PeriodFormatter`) - see also the right answer of @Isaksson.

Answer (score 8):

You can build a formatter for your format and use that. To get the time in seconds only normalized to minutes/seconds, use `normalizedStandard()`;

```
PeriodFormatter myFormat =
    new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendMinutes()
        .appendSeparator(":")
        .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();

Period period = Period.seconds(110).normalizedStandard();
System.out.println(myFormat.print(period));

> 01:50
```

Comment: Note: minutes seem to wrap with this solution, i.e. for a time of 3660 seconds (61 minutes) the display will be `01:00`, not `61:00`.

Comment: Which is logical since you're not printing hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date dt = new Date();
    String date = String.format("%tH:%tM", dt, dt);
    System.out.println(date);
    // or System.out.printf("%tH:%tM", dt, dt);
}
```